# Regex to determine branch from svn repository URL

Tags: regex, svn, ant

I'm executing 'svn info --xml' and got an svn-repositories URL.

Now I want to know the branch it is on (or trunk).

The url's may look like this:

https://svn-domain.com/Tech/Product/branches/Version_1.0/folder

https://svn-domain.com/Tech/Product/branches/Version_1.0

https://svn-domain.com/Product/trunk/folder

https://svn-domain.com/Product/trunk

How will a regex pattern look that returns trunk or the branch-name after /branches/ ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using [positive lookbehind assertion](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) (`(?<= ...)`) with `|`

```
(?<=/)trunk\b|(?<=/branches/)[^/]+
```

Above will match `trunk` preceded by `/` OR branch name (that consist of non-`/` characters) preceded by `/branches/`.

NOTE

- According to your regular expression engine, you may need to escape `/`.
- Some regular expression engine (for example javascript) does not support lookbehind assertion.

Comment: I'm using JavaScript so there is no positive lookbehind. How to determine the branch after /branches/ and leave the part after the next / out

Comment: @Hedge, How about this? `var matched = 'https://svn-domain.com/Tech/Product/branches/Version_1.0/folder'.match(/\/(trunk\b)|\/branches\/([^/]+)/); var branch_name = matched && (matched[1] || matched[2])`

Comment: Yes it works. Instead of matching for trunk, I just assume it as a default-value when there are no matches.

Comment: @Hedge, Sorry, but I don't understand what do you want by reading the last sentence in your comment.

Comment: Sorry for the bad description. I was able to figure it out myself. Now everything is working as expected. Thanks a lot.

Comment: @Hedge, Could you share what you figured out?